# Finding center of circle in image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following two images:

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

**How can I determine the center of the seen circle in both images?**

I found different answers, which are similar ([links](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bimage-processing%5D%20find%20circle)) to my question, but due to the squared structure around the circle I am not able to find a solution for my images.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative can be using `ImageCorrelate`. First I create the target object by cropping the original image - it doesn't have to be precise. Here I use `ImageTake` so that you can verify the results.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzFtr.png"];

circ = ImageTake[img, {120, 210}, {70, 159}]
```

[image]

```
f=ImageCorrelate[img, circ, NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance];
pos = Binarize[f, 0.2];
cen=Mean[ImageValuePositions[pos, 0]]

Show[img, Epilog -> {Red, Point[cen]}]
```

[image]

So stepwise it is

[image]

and `cen` is the average of `pos`.

Using the same `circ` on the second image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7r2V.png"]
f = ImageCorrelate[img, circ, NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance];
pos = Binarize[f, 0.2];
cen = Mean[ImageValuePositions[pos, 0]]

Show[img, Epilog -> {Red, Point[cen]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, it works although the full circle is not visible here.

Comment: Fun,since we can get the `circ`,why not use `Mean[{{120, 210}, {70, 159}}]` to get the center? :)

Comment: @yode, you need to do that only once from any image of a huge stack of images. And it does not have to be very accurate (I have a little extra space at bottom of circ). Now imagine you have 100 different images - you don't want to do this manual cropping 100 times ;)

Comment: Thank you ... please see also my comment to yode concerning the center and the crossing point of the lines ...

Comment: If you print `f`, you will see that it is actually the crossing point (the darkest point). `pos` gives you the center location - not the full ring. Since it is a bunch of closely placed points - I took the average.

Answer (score 5):

There maby be a better method can hough detect circle.Just some thinking strike to my mind.So I think the method based on `GradientOrientationFilter` also can serve this target.

Use the method from [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149664/21532) to get a ridge image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7r2V.png"];
binImg = DeleteSmallComponents[
   ColorNegate[
    DeleteSmallComponents[
     MorphologicalBinarize[PeronaMalikFilter[img, 10], .2], 100]]];
ske = Thinning[
  MorphologicalBinarize[
   ImageAdjust[binImg~Blur~12~Erosion~6~RidgeFilter~1], {.3, .5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use the direction information to show the `ske`

```
orientation = GradientOrientationFilter[ske, 2] // ImageAdjust;
color = ImageAdjust[
  ImageMultiply[ColorCombine[{orientation, ske, ske}, "HSB"], ske]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select that segment include most color

```
circle = Pruning[DeleteSmallComponents[
   ImageFilter[If[#[[2, 2]] != {0, 0, 0}, 
      If[Count[Catenate[#], #[[2, 2]]] >= 5, {0, 0, 
        0}, #[[2, 2]]], {0, 0, 0}] &, color, 2, Interleaving -> True]], 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's show the center of the circle

```
pos = ImageValuePositions[Binarize[circle, 0], 1]
HighlightImage[img, {PointSize[.05],Point@Values[Most[FindFit[
      PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pos, (x - m)^2 + (y - n)^2 - r^2, {m, n, r}, {x, y}]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the **same** code also can be applied to another image and will get a perfect result.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: great ... thank you

Comment: @lio See the update.I have finished it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help .. instead of selecting the circle it would be interesting to compare with the crossing point of the vertical and horizontal line which are going through the circle and also defining its center. May be this is more accurate.