# How to get a smooth ridge from a binary image

Tags: image-processing, smoothing

I always have this demand,but *Mathematica* cannot implement this perfectly for me.For example,I have such binary image

```
binImg = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
     Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mJL2.png"],"Byte"]]]]
BinaryImageQ[binImg]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> True

I want to get a smooth ridge as far as possible.This is current method I can think out.

```
Pruning[Thinning[binImg], 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course,the `SkeletonTransform` can provide a little bit better result.But I have to say there is a long way to go.I mean I hope to get a result,the line more like a line,a rectangle more like a rectangle,a circle more like a circle in the result ridge image.In my case,I hope the result will **more close** to following red commponent.

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like `ImageAdjust[binImg~Blur~12~Erosion~6~RidgeFilter~1]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Magic,man.. :)

Comment: @SimonWoods And you don't intend to post it as a answer?That will be  a wonderful start I think.

Comment: I don't know Mathematica, but morphological processing (successive dilation and erosion) will go a long way.

Answer (score 19):

You could try some kind of blurring or low-pass filter to smooth out some of the irregularity. For example

```
ImageAdjust[binImg ~Blur~ 12 ~Erosion~ 6 ~RidgeFilter~ 1]
```

[image]

Comment: I always think the upvote is a mysterious thing.Anyway,that include my one. :)

Answer (score 5):

Almost

```
Thinning@SkeletonTransform@Binarize[Blur[binImg, 10], Method -> "Entropy"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]