# How to make the boundaries thin and smooth of a binary image?

Tags: image-processing

Consider a binary image `img` as

[image]

How can I make the edges thin and smooth?

Comment: Have you tried `Thinning`?

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, it works. Although the roughness is still there.

Comment: Related [my this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149661/how-to-get-a-smooth-ridge-from-a-binary-image)

Answer (score 6):

You can get it to be a little smoother by dilating before the thinning:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Vet.png"]
Thinning[Dilation[img, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Just about any smoothing before thinning works:

`Thinning[Binarize[GaussianFilter[img, 3]]]` produces very similar results with maybe slightly smoother eyes.

Answer (score 3):

Riding off Bill's answer, we can smooth further by upsampling with `ImageMesh`, thinning, then downsampling.

```
img = ImageCrop[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Vet.png"]];
imsmall = Thinning[Dilation[img, 1]];

mesh = ImageMesh[imsmall, ImageSize -> 1200, 
  Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> White, Method -> "DualMarchingCubes"];

imlarge = Thinning[Dilation[Rasterize[mesh, "Image"], 12]];

res = Thinning[Binarize[ImageResize[imlarge, ImageDimensions[img]]]]
```

[image]

### Edit

Notice one side of each feature boundary is fairly smooth. I exploit this with a very manual approach:

```
level1 = Thinning[EdgeDetect[FillingTransform[img]]];

level2 = Thinning[EdgeDetect[FillingTransform[Dilation[
  ImageDifference[img, GeodesicClosing[img, 14]], 1]]]];

level3 = Thinning[EdgeDetect[Dilation[
  ImageDifference[img, GeodesicClosing[img, 8]], 1]]];

res = level1 + level2 + level3
```

[image]

```
Dilation[res, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any python implementation of this?

Comment: Can you please help me with which language this is written? @Chip

Comment: @Bharath_Raja https://www.wolfram.com/language/

Comment: Where can I find the documentation and list of operations used in the above solution?

Comment: Here’s an example. You can search for others on the same site. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is picking out the components and then approximating each component with a smooth spline. I tried with BSpline and Bezier, perhaps it can be used as a start.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Vet.png"];
components = MorphologicalComponents[img];
components // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example, one of the components can be approximated like this:

```
pts = RandomSample[Position[components, 2], 100];
{dist, order} = FindShortestTour[pts];
pts = Part[pts, order];
BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 100] // Graphics
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The spline degree was chosen by experimenting. The shape is not a perfect circle, but it is rather smooth. Now we do the same for the rest of the components:

```
smoothComponent[comp_, splineType : "Bezier" | "BSpline"] := Module[{pts, dist, order},
  pts = RandomSample[Position[components, comp], 80];
  {dist, order} = FindShortestTour[pts];
  pts = Part[pts, order];
  If[
   splineType == "BSpline",
   BSplineCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 100],
   BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 15]
   ]
  ]

bspline = smoothComponent[#, "BSpline"] & /@ Range[2, 9];
ImageRotate[Graphics[bspline], -90 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bezier = smoothComponent[#, "Bezier"] & /@ Range[2, 9];
ImageRotate[Graphics[bezier], -90 Degree]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Especially the Bezier curve didn't turn out that well. I mainly wanted to show this alternative type of answer, which is different from the image processing solutions so far.

Parameters to play with: How many points to sample from each component, and what the spline degree should be for the Bezier curve and BSpline respectively.